# List repositories that use specific submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have several git repositories (projects), which use other repositories ("components") as subodules:

```
Project 1
 - Component A
 - Component B
Project 2
 - Component B
 - Component C
Project 3
 - Component A
 - Component B
```

All repositories are side-by-side on the same server:

```
 - Project 1
 - Project 2
 - Project 3
 - Component A
 - Component B
 - Component C
```

I want to find out in which project Component B is used. More specific: in which project a *specific commit* - or a descendant of it - of Component B is used.

My approach: Create a database of all submodules that stores their commit hashes. Then iterate through all parents of the specific commit and see whether they're in the database.

Do you know a better solution, maybe using only git commands?

Do you know an application/project/library that (partly) solves my problem?

Comment: git is already a database of commits, so first is that there's no need for another one

Comment: @CharlesB: I think they'll be bare repositories on a git hosting server. Ok, instead of a storing the submodules in a database one could look for the `.gitmodules` files in each branch of each repository, although that might be slower.

Comment: Hi
I made "crappy" script that might actually be able to help you, but you have to modify to your needs :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I made minor script for a colleague today 
That wanted to know which "versions" of a given submodule was used in all the sha1 in the supermodule.

```
#!/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $command = "";
my $submodule = $ARGV[0];
my $submodule_sha = "";
my @commits = ();
my %commit_hash = ();
my $commit = "";
my $key = "";
my $value = "";
$command="git log --since=\"1 week ago\" --format=format:%H";
@commits=`$command`;
foreach $commit (@commits)
{
    #cleaning the $commit
    $commit =~ s/\s+$//;
    $commit =~ s/^\s+//;
    $command="git ls-tree $commit \| grep $submodule \|  cut -d\" \" -f3 |cut -f1";
    print $command . "\n";
    $submodule_sha=`$command`;
    $commit_hash{$commit} = $submodule_sha;
}    

while (($key, $value) = each(%commit_hash)){
    print $key.", ".$value."\n";
}
```

Execute like this

you should be in the supermodule

./scriptname.pl submodulename

Basically i am just taking advantage of the git ls-tree command
If you are in the supermodule you can do 
    git ls-tree HEAD | grep "submodulename"
This will give you the commit for the submodule.

There might be a smarter way, but this deals with the problem : )

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find all the repos using a given repo as a submodule with the github search engine:

**From the Github UI:**

Past the following string in the search bar and replace with the repo of your choice:

```
owner_name/repo_name path:**/.gitmodules
```

Then select `Code` in the search result type.

It will list all the `.gitmodules` files containing `owner_name/repo_name`.

**From GitHub URL:**

```
https://github.com/search?q=owner_name%2Frepo_name+path%3A**%2F.gitmodules&type=code
```

Example: https://github.com/search?q=redhawk-dependencies%2FomniEvents+path%3A**%2F.gitmodules&type=code

**From Github API**

```
curl -H 'Authorization: token YOUR_TOKEN' https://api.github.com/search/code?q=owner_name/repo_name+filename:.gitmodules
```

**From Github CLI**

You can do it with the Githuc CLI [search code command](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_search_code)

```
gh search code "owner_name/repo_name" --filename .gitmodules
```

---

For a reason I don't understand, the API/CLI method return less results than the UI/URL methods...

---

Linked threads :

- [Is there a way to find all repos referencing this repo as a submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66755760/is-there-a-way-to-find-all-repos-referencing-this-repo-as-a-submodule)
- [how to know if repository is a submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41121117/how-to-know-if-repository-is-a-submodule)