# how to know if repository is a submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

Pretend that I have repo A, and its submodules A.1 and A.2.

If I run

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/A/A.git .
```

It will clone the main repository and its submodules.

But if I run:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/A/A1.git .
```

I can't run anything that can handle the main repo and other submodules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot know whether a repository is a submodule or not. Each repository used as a submodule somewhere else is a full own standalone repository. That it is used in some other repository as submodule is purely defined by that master repository (or repositories). You can use one repository also as submodule repository for an arbitrary amount of master repositories. This is like asking "How do I know that package `java.util.regex` is used by other packages" or "How do I know that log4j is used by other software as library".

Comment: Can't we do `cd ..` and see is the submode_repo is in the submodule list of the parent folder?

Comment: No, because that was not the question. OP clones the repo that is a submodule, so the parent module is nowhere available on disk.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if there's a 100% reliable way of knowing since every submodule is a fully-fledged proper repository. However, you could use the fact that, when you clone a repo with submodules, then the submodule folders will have a `.git` file, as opposed to the main (top-level) repo that has a `.git` folder. As such:

```
test -d .git; echo $?
```

will print `1` if you're in a submodule and `0` if you're in the top-level repo. To make it also work from within subfolders:

```
(cd `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` && test -d .git); echo $?
```

If you're using this in a shell script, there's no need to `echo` the return value of course, you could just use the result of the subshell directly.

Comment: That was not the question, was it? OP asked if you checkout the submodule repo on its own, how you tell that it is used as a submodule in some other repo and maybe even automatically get the master repo and the other sibling subrepos which plainly is impossible.

Comment: @Vampire I am not entirely clear whether the question was about scripting taking submodules into account, or about checking out a master after a submodule. If your interpretation is correct then so is your answer so I am upvoting that.

Comment: This commands only work if you have downloaded the top repo. If you just download the "subrepo", .git is present