# Is there a way to find all repos referencing this repo as a submodule?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have several repos that have a repo (let's call it R) in them as a submodule. Is there a way I can find all of those repos referencing R using command line?

Comment: Not in general, no. In fact, I may have some repository on my own machine here using some repository of yours as a submodule, without ever having told you that I did that. At best, you can look at some set of repositories and determine if those repositories have `.gitmodules` files in their commits and if so, what URLs those `.gitmodules` files have in them.

Comment: Ah good point yeah that makes sense. I'll have to keep a list of the referencing repos in the referenced repo then.

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: @TejasKale I don't remember now but I think I was trying to do some dependency management of a large project where I was working back then. I think the build artifacts of many projects were packaged together in a pipeline and I wanted to make sure all those sub-projects use the same version of some dependencies.